# Uniqueness of representation of a quantum system in polar coordinates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, coordinate-systems, spherical-harmonics

Are [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) the only possible Hilbert basis for a polar description of a quantum system? In other words, is the following representation for a wave function $\Psi(\theta, \phi):$

$$\Psi (\theta, \phi ) = \sum_{l,m} c_{_{l,m}}\ Y^{^m}_{_l} (\theta, \phi)$$

- always possible?
- unique?

Comment: Is a basis of a vector space ever unique?

Comment: do you know other Hilbert bases of the form $f(\theta, \phi)$?

Comment: any invertible transformation of spherical harmonics for example as noted in DanielC's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the 3D spherical harmonics $Y^{l}_{m} (\theta, \phi)$  form an orthonormal basis in the Hilbert space $L^2 (S^2, d\Omega)$. Since any unitary transformation of an orthonormal basis produces a new base, then your two questions receive an easy answer.

Comment: What is an orthonormal basis and why do we care about it?

Comment: It is really complicated to explain here. Read a good texbook of quantum mechanics.

Comment: I want to learn it instantly without having to read a book

Comment: @RyanParikh Do you understand what an orthonormal basis is in Euclidean space?

Comment: @G.Smith Isn't it when the coordinate axes are all at 90 degrees to each other

Comment: @RyanParikh Yes, and where the basis vectors have length 1. In Hilbert space, you have a similar situation but there can be an infinite number of dimensions so there are an infinite number of basis vectors, and they are generally written as functions since they have an infinite number of components. “Being at 90 degrees” means having a scalar product that is zero. In an infinite- dimensional Hilbert space the scalar product is an integral rather than a finite sum.

Comment: @RyanParikh I wanted to give you a short answer, but I don’t want to take over the comments on Daniel’s answer to talk about this more. You can always ask questions about bases, Hilbert spaces, etc. on Math SE.